# Sharepoint list field 'Created by' shows username

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-list, power-automate, domain, microsoft-forms

I created a workflow that every form that is submitted gets recorded in sharepoint list. The flow works perfectly, but the 'created by' field does not show the user name of the person who submitted the form, but instead every entry shows my domain id.

The forms are only filled and submitted by people within my organisation.

This was initially working by now it only shows my domain if.

Comment: Easy solution would be: You can create a new person or group column in list and set it using Power Automate with the name of person who submitted form.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, but I'm trying to understand what could I have changed for this to only show my name.. an additional fact is that have changed the member permission to read only and removed create and edit rights from the list settings

Comment: How you were setting created by field before with the name of person who submitted the form? Which action you were using for this? Permissions will not change automatically (might be someone from your team changed it or is there any logic to change permissions in your flow?)